# Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA) issue on Jenkins slave node in Selenium tests

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, single-sign-on

**Given**: We have a Jenkins build running Selenium tests for application using using SSO authentication.Application and authentication provider are located in corporate intranet of type
"auth-service-name.corp-name.com". Tests are running fine on local Windows machine, but on Jenkins windows environment they can't pass IWA to access the tested website. Application tested works ONLY in Chrome, so it is the browser used in tests. In registries of Jenkins machine it was found out that there is a proxy set up, while on local machine there is no proxy.

**Tried**: sending http requests with login and pass for sso-provider page. starting chrome in jenkins via command line with(start chrome --auth-server-whitelist=
"*corp-name.com")

**Question**: Is there any way to bypass such an issue? What could cause that Jenkins machine can't pass IWA?

Comment: maybe check this: https://plugins.jenkins.io/active-directory/

Comment: Thank you for response. Have no chance to work with setting this plugin because have no permissions to do that as setting jenkins configuration is a job of another team. There is no guarantee that after 2 weeks of mailing it would become clear that issue is an another destination. There is certainly some problem on Windows-Chrome-Ping layer